# UIImage and resizableImageWithCapInsets Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uiimage

I'm newer with Swift's Apple. I had read an article from [Here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/ios-5-uiimage-and-resizableimagewithcapinsets.html)

But don't know how to do something like that(or just simple don't know how to use `resizableImageWithCapInsets` with Swift). Please help me to use `resizableImageWithCapInsets` in Swift

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Generic way in Xcode 6.1 is:

1. Create an UIImage as a variable
2. Create an insets
3. Create a new image based on the original image and the insets, and assign it to the   original image

---

```
var myImage = UIImage(named: "navbar.png")!
let myInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(13, 37, 13, 37)
myImage = myImage.resizableImageWithCapInsets(myInsets)
```

Comment: in case your original image is small and you don't want to title it then use below function myImage.resizableImage(withCapInsets: myInsets, resizingMode: .stretch)