# bubble icon factory for google maps in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps

I had earlier used the google map util library to plot bubble icon in google maps  and now I would like to do the same for iOS

[image: bubble icons]

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/

I found this pod for iOS https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils

Has anybody used it to create bubble icons and if so how do i create a bubble icons for iOS ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such utility for IOS. I needed a similar solution, so I've come with the below.

The below function draws a left arrow and returns an UIImage. Note that one can draw the arrow by using only paths. Also, one can also use a pre created image from assets instead of creating all the time or create one re-use it.

```
func drawArrow() ->UIImage {

    //the color of the arrow
    let color = UIColor.yellow

    // First create empty image choose the size according to your need.
    let width = 84
    let height = 24

    let size = CGSize( width: width, height: height)

    //let image: UIImage = makeEmptyImage(size: size)

    let rectangle = CGRect(x: 12, y: 0, width: 72, height: 24)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( size,  false,  0.0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    //clear the background
    context?.clear(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))

    //draw the rectangle
    context?.addRect(rectangle)
    context?.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context?.fill(rectangle)

    //draw the triangle
    context?.beginPath()
    context?.move(   to: CGPoint(x : 12 ,y :  0) )
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x :  0, y : 12) )
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x : 12, y : 24) )
    context?.closePath()

    context?.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context?.fillPath()

    // get the image
    let image2 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image2
}
```

The next function, takes the image and draw a text onto it.

```
func drawText(text:NSString, inImage:UIImage) -> UIImage? {

    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)
    let color = UIColor.black
    let style : NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
    style.alignment = .center

    let attributes:NSDictionary = [ NSAttributedString.Key.font :               font,
                                    NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle :     style,
                                    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor :    color
    ]

    let myInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    let newImage = inImage.resizableImage(withCapInsets: myInsets)

    print("rect.width \(inImage.size.width) rect.height \(inImage.size.height)")


    let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: attributes as? [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] )

    let textRect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: textSize.width, height: textSize.height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: textSize.width + 20, height: textSize.height + 10), false, 0.0)

    newImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textSize.width + 20 , height: textSize.height + 10))

    text.draw(in: textRect.integral, withAttributes: attributes as? [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]  )

    let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return resultImage
}
```

so we can use it like

```
marker.icon = drawText(text: eLoc.name as NSString, inImage: drawArrow() )

marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)

//If you need some rotation          
//let degrees = CLLocationDegrees(exactly: 90.0)
//marker.rotation = degrees!
```

`groundAnchor` moves the position of the marker icon, see this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28960100/8738452). With degree you can rotate the arrow.

Note : Unfortunately, IOS doesn't support 9-patch images. Therefore, not all of the bubble icon factory can be programmed by using resizableImage, see this nice [web site](https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-stretchable-button-uiedgeinsetsmake/) and also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26697708/8738452)

An example output is;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you check out the customize icon [**documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/marker#customize_a_marker) for google maps ios sdk? It's a good start.

Comment: yes i have however, I need a label inside the marker with a customized image, something that was possible with the google map utility library for android https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/ but this one I can't use for iOS